# Cancel draggable div on start

Tags: jquery, draggable

**What I have:**
Draggable divs that have an alert on start and revert when dropped.

**What I need:**
When user tries to drag the div, an alert pops up saying you can't drag it and the dragging stops before it even goes anywhere.

Comment: A) So why bother with the draggable in the first place and B) What have you tried?

Comment: can you give a piece of code...

Comment: @j08691 if I had to guess he probably need to enable/disable dragging according to the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `return false` within the [`start()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start) method to accomplish this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        alert('Dragging is disabled');
        return false;
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jam8Z/