# jQuery draggable - fire event when user grabs the draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm using jQuery UI to make a list of elements draggable/droppable.

Here is the gist of the code:

```
$(elem).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    var dragElem = $(ui.draggable).clone();     //identify element
    //replace elements etc
    ...
```

This works fine, and upon dropping the element, everything goes smoothly.

However, in one scenario I need to be able to execute some code at the moment when the user grabs the element with his mouse. I can't find any docs explaining how to do that, but I presume it should be possible.

Something like

```
$(elem).droppable({
        grab: function(event, ui) {
            //do stuff
```

would make sense, no? Anyone know the correct syntax to use here?

Comment: wouldn't you need to use the draggable for when the user grabs it? - http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start

Comment: I suppose - and how would I tell it to drop the element immediately if a condition is met? Within the `start()` event I would like to do something like `if(condition) drop-theelement-now`.

Comment: I think you just return false if your condition is met: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913338/cancel-draggable-div-on-start

Comment: Do you want the event when user starts dragging the draggable with the mouse ?

Comment: The answer to your question is already given, if it is not the answer you expected, please provide more details like what exactly you're trying to do..

Comment: The 'start' event is what I needed and it works, the answer below however is not what I was looking for. If @Pete adds an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `activate` event, which is fired when dragging starts:

```
$(elem).droppable({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        //do stuff
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dragElem = $(ui.draggable).clone();     
        // identify element
        // replace elements etc
    }
});
```

Further info on the event available in the [jQueryUI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-activate)

Comment: What if 'do stuff' is 'drop the element immediately'? Do you know how I would do that?